# Google Cloud Function: "Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted." when deploying NLP model

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to deploy an NLP model which has been trained in Tesorflow 2.0 beta.  I use `model.save('pb_model')` to save model in .pb format (this gives me pb_model.pb and variables folders as usual).

I placed pb files in Google Cloud storage bucket which all together are about 370Mb.  I am using Google Cloud Functions since this is currently the only serverless platform which supports TF 2.0.  For my GCP Function, I selected the highest memory allocation available which is currently 2Gb.  I trigger my Function with an HTTP request.

My `main.py` code looks like this:

```
import sys
import os
import psutil
import shutil
import tensorflow as tf

import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.cloud import storage

model = None

class CustomModel():
    def __init__(self):
        print('Starting CustomModel build...')
        print('1:', psutil.virtual_memory())
        dirName = '/tmp/model_dir/variables/'

        # Create target directory & all intermediate directories if don't exists
        os.makedirs(dirName, exist_ok=True)

        pb_model_dir = 'gs://<cloud_bucket_name>/model_dir'  # storage bucket file path of pb files
        model = tf.saved_model.load(pb_model_dir)
        shutil.rmtree('/tmp/model_dir', ignore_errors=True) # remove tmp files to maintain low memory
        print('loaded model')
        return model

def handler(request):
    global model

    # Model load which only happens during cold starts
    if model is None:
        model = CustomModel()

    model_inputs = <some input text>
    predictions = model(model_inputs)
    print(predictions)

    return predictions
```

When looking at the logs, the output of print statement `print('1:', psutil.virtual_memory())` shows that I have 1.9Gb free out of the allocated 2Gb, before the model is loaded.

When I run this exact code on Google Colab, the maximum amount of memory which is occupied by the loaded model is about 0.9Gb.  Therefore, in principle, that means that when I deploy model in GCP Function, 2Gb is more than enough for my model however I keep getting the memory limit exceeded error:

> Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?  Am I constructing GCP Function correctly?  I'm still kinda of new to GCP.  Btw, I even tried to import pb model files from bucket into my Function /tmp/ folder instead of pointing to bucket path (`pb_model_dir = 'gs://<cloud_bucket_name>/model_dir'`) but that also gives me memory limit exceeded error. 
 Not sure what else to try... Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Cloud Function isn't the only one platform to serve model in serverless way. [I wrote an article with Tensorflow1 and Cloud Run](https://medium.com/google-cloud/portable-prediction-with-tensorflow-and-cloud-run-669c1c73ebd1). You can try something equivalend with your model. I have to update my model in Tensorflow2 and publish a new version of this article with Tensorflow2. But I lack of time by now... Tell me if this helps

Comment: Thank you for your links and suggesting Cloud Run serverless platform.  I checked out Cloud Run and they also have a **maximum memory allocation of 2Gb**.  Technically my Tensorflow 2.0 pb files should work with Cloud Function but I keep hitting `memory limit exceeded` error and I think I will get same error with Cloud Run since that also has 2Gb memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

There could be more reasons for this situation to be encountered. As I can see that you are already aware, temporary files can be a cause of a memory leak. Temporary files can also be created from errors, or warnings. First of all, I would check my function logs for errors and warnings and I would try to fix them.

As I see your Cloud Function is interacting a lot with the storage bucket. This causes high queries per second which might be a possible reason for the Cloud Function instance to fail, because of the GCS errors. This issue was encountered before and as you can see [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1253), it was mitigated by treating the GCS errors. So, I would suggest to investigate more following this path, go where your function interacts with the bucket and try to treat the possible errors coming from the bucket.

Another thing that you can do is investigate a bit the way of the memory is used in your function. For this you have some nice tools you can use like [Heap Checker](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy) and  [Pympler](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/).

If these is not the issue, I would ask you to show some logs(from CF and Storage Bucket) and some tests for the function, because on a first look, your code looks fine to me.

You may also take into consideration using another method to achieve your technical purpose. You have [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/how-to-serve-deep-learning-models-using-tensorflow-2-0-with-cloud-functions) more information than can present you all the options you have.

Comment: Thank you.  Here are the logs of my CF:

> Function execution started
> Starting CustomModel build...
> 1: svmem(total=2147483648, available=1925939200, percent=10.3, used=119214080, free=1925939200, active=170369024, inactive=51163136, buffers=0, cached=102330368, shared=4096, slab=0)
> Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted.

Memory limit exceeded error is raised at line `model = tf.saved_model.load(pb_model_dir)`. 

My CF should only be loading model once at start of invocation.  How do you use Heap Checker or Pympler while model is being loaded ?

Comment: For Pympler, in the link from the my answer there is an usage example. You can see the memory of model with this line of code: asizeof.asized(model, detail=1).format(). You can also test it locally.